# Microsoft Graph API - not able to use orderby or filter on createdDateTime for Sites

Tags: sorting, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sites

I want to query Sites using Microsoft Graph API that were created after a certain time.  So I created the following filter query:

```
createdDateTime ge 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

I also tried:

```
createdDateTime ge `2023-01-01T00:00:00Z`
```

Both generated an invalid request error with no details.

I then tried just doing an orderby createdDateTime.  This did "work" but it sorted each page, not the whole dataset.  So page 2 had items that should have been in page 1 and so on.

Microsoft Graph API seems really crappy.  Does anybody know how to achieve this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you are using [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-1.0), then I have to said the odata query may not supported well for this since the document doesn't mention the `createdDateTime` is supported by filter.

Comment: As a [versa example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters), you can see content in this section, it will let you know the advanced query.

Answer (score 1):

I've never found a way how to use filter on `/sites` endpoint.

I'm using `/search/query` endpoint for searching SharePoint sites based on some criterion.

You should be able to specify filter by `Created` and properties for sorting.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query

{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "site"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "Created > 2022-01-01 AND Created < 2022-12-31"
            },
            "from": 0,
            "size": 25,
            "sortProperties": [
                {
                    "name": "Created",
                    "isDescending": "false"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```